# Current waveform in an inductor with AC source

Tags: ac, inductor, electromagnetism

If we connect an AC source with a pure inductor when AC source is going through 0 volts we get the following graph of the voltage and current.

There are few things in the graph about which i am confused.

In the first graph/diagram "A" of the picture which shows the voltage when it starts to flow and the corresponding current, the current doesnt seem to be lagging behind the voltage by 90 degrees. What is the reason behind that? Is the statement "current lags behind the voltage in an inductor BY 90 degree" is valid just for the steady state voltage shown in graph "B"?

Second confusion is that for the first half cycle of the voltage in graph "A", current is rising both for increasing and decreasing voltage. How is this possible that current is rising in the inductor for both increasing and decreasing voltage?

[image]

Comment: Can you plot a voltage across a capacitor when we connect an empty capacitor across an AC current source \$I= I_O \: sin \: \omega t\$? One cycle will be enough.

Comment: why there is dc offset in this circuit? can you give me intuition about that ? @G36 ?

Comment: We have a DC offset because of the current is starting from 0A and the voltage too at power-up (initial condition).

Comment: can you please give me the intuition that how resistance will finish this dc off set ?

Comment: But can you tell me fist do you understand what in this circuit https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWAIg.png the voltage across the capacitor keeps rising despite the fact that the current decreases for t  > 10ms?

Comment: yes i think . thats because although current is decreasing but yet charges are flowing and more and more charges are accumulating on the plates of capacitor. and this makes the voltage increase.

Comment: Yes, good answer. And exactly the same thing happening in the inductor during positive -cycle. This is why the current in the inductor is rising all the time during a positive-cycle.  And remember that the inductor is the opposite of a capacitor.  And stores the energy in the form of a magnetic field. And because of this an inductors are not so intuitive to understand as capacitors is.

Comment: you mean although voltage decreases during second positive half cycle but yet the voltage is positive so the current will be increasing ?

Comment: @G36 yes there is so mess in inductor. really i never found anything hard to understand than inductor.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant. See with the Capacitor version (capacitor driven by current source ) https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFxy8.png

Comment: And I hope the you understand why we have a "DC-offset" in the circuit with the capacitor

Comment: hey its the exact graph , only voltage and current replace each other, and the capacitor has a dc off set of voltage and inductor has the dc off set of current.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107236/discussion-between-alex-and-g36).

Comment: OK I need to go to sleep now. It's almost midnight. And tomorrow I need to go to work.

Comment: please give me your fb link @G36

Comment: but i dont understand now why current will remain positive for the negative half cycle ? please give me the hint about it as well. @G36

Comment: please answer here @G36 https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/495977/why-the-inrush-current-increase-with-decreasing-voltage/495986#495986

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the current is lagging the voltage by 90 degrees throughout the entire graph. What is confusing you is that the current has a DC offset. This DC offset is actually the 'transient' solution, and it does not die off because there is no resistance (dissipation) in this circuit.

> Second confusion is that for the first half cycle of the voltage in graph "A", current is rising both for increasing and decreasing voltage. How is this possible that current is rising in the inductor for both increasing and decreasing voltage ?

This is the behavior you expect because of the relationship between voltage and current:

$$V = L\frac{dI}{dt}$$

So if V is positive, \$dI/dt\$ is positive, and therefore the current I is rising. I is increasing any time V is positive, not when \$dV/dt\$ is positive.

Comment: thank you. can you please give me the intuition that how will this transient die off when resistance is added in this circuit ?

Comment: @Alex there is no transient decay in this circuit as there is no resistor. The circuit reaches steady state at t = 0.

Comment: @Alex There would be many ways of describing intuitively how a resistor would cause the dc current to die off. One way to think of it is that the voltage source is pushing current around symmetrically -- positive and negative. If the current has a dc offset, then a resistor pushes 'back' on the current asymmetrically, since a resistor always pushes 'against' the current. Eventually the dc goes away until the resistor is pushing symmetrically too, since the current going through it is symmetric. Not a great intuitive description, but maybe that will help.

Comment: so if this circuit has a resistance , there would be no transient or dc offset ?

Comment: @Alex If it had a resistance, you would see the current waveform start off with an offset, but then that offset would decay until it is gone....i.e. you reach the 'steady state' solution.

Comment: ok but why do we have this dc offset ? last question, intuition please

Comment: @Alex The offset is there because of the initial conditions (V=0, I=0). If you were to start it off with just the right conditions, such as V=0, I=-\$1/\omega L\$, there would be no offset (transient solution).

Comment: I = -1/wL ? whats that ?

Comment: @Alex  \$\omega\$ is frequency of your voltage sine wave, L is the value of your inductor.

Comment: wL is reactance and I=V/wL. how can you write -1 /wL ?

Comment: @Alex My last post here...sorry. I am using your graph to conclude your voltage input waveform is a sine wave with amplitude 1 Volt, and some frequency \$\omega\$ that you can figure out. I am saying that if you want to launch right into the steady-state solution so that there is no transient, you could do so if you start off with the current being negative, with a value of -(1 Volt/\$\omega L\$), where you simply plug in the numbers for \$\omega\$ and for L.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the inductor current lagging the voltage by 90 degreees in an AC circuit is valid for steady-state.  Any transient solution has to die out before the steady-state solution dominates.

An inductor follows the relationship:   $$\ V=L*di/dt $$  Therefore the current is proportional to the integral of the voltage across it.  Increasing or decreasing, as long as the polarity is the same the inductor will "accumulate" current.

When the polarity of the applied voltage flips, you can see that the rate of change of current is zero at the zero crossing of the voltage.

Comment: "Any transient solution has to die out before the steady-state solution dominates." how will transient die in this case. normally resistance do the job. but can you please give me an intuition that how resistor will finish transient in this case ?

Comment: Well in the case of a pure inductance and ideal source you're right, the inductor will "remember" the transient and it could be an offset to the steady-state solution.  Steady-state by definition means "after any transient solution has died out".  If the transient solution persists due to zero damping (no resistance) then you will never reach steady-state. (See the third graph from the top in your question.)

Comment: can you give me an intuition that how damping will happen in this case ? i am not getting it.